# Unable to connect to SQL Server database using mssql and expressjs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database from expressjs using `mssql`, but I keep getting this:

[image: error]

I am following the example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connections-1

The code in my app.js is as follows

```
const config = {
    //user: '',
    //password: '',
    server: 'LAPTOP-A7INMDKJ',
    database: 'dbone'
}   

sql.on('error', (err)=> {
    // error handler
});
sql.connect(config).then(
    (pool) =>{
        return pool.request()
                    .query('select * from course');
    }).
    then(result=> {
        console.log('dasdasdsa');
        console.log(result);
    }).
    catch( (err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I Component services I have this

[image: Component services screenshot]

and in computer management tcp/ip is enabled

[image: computer management screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? I am using Windows authentication for SQL Server.

Comment: Try localhost or 127.0.0.1 as host; make sure MSSQL is turned on and listens throughout firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

The normal troubleshooting process is to verify:

1. SQL Server has TCP/IP enabled and is configured to listen on port 1433 in Configuration Manager.
2. SQL Server is running and the SQL Server Error log has an entry like `Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].`
3. The Windows Firewall is not blocking inbound TCP connections on port 1433
4. The client can resolve the SQL Server's hostname correctly
5. The client can connect over TCP/IP to port 1433 on the SQL Server, eg by powershell's `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName [sqlserverhostname] -Port 1433`